# HDMI signal interrputs after 10 minutes plugged in a TV

Tags: vlc, hdmi, jupiter

Ubuntu 11.10, Dell Inspiron N4050, VLC, Jupiter

I'm trying to watch movies through HDMI output on a TV,
with VLC, with the notebook unplugged from AC (but with enough battery for 2-3 hours of use), just with TV display (the notebook display stays off)
And from 10 to 10 minutes, the TV turns black, and according to the TV, the HDMI cable is unplugged.

But using the touchpad makes the screen appear again.
In "screen" options, on system settings, i've set the screen to never  turn off, and never reduce brightness using battery. In "power" settings, i've set to not suspend when using battery.
In Jupiter, i've set (while trying to watch the movie) to work in maximum performance.
I'm pretty sure it's not VLC, because i've set it to override power options and screensaver options (and also im not using xscreensaver). Also the movie continues, when the screen is black

Maybe there's something that i'm missing?
When i plug the HDMI in the notebook, i use jupiter to change the display (using the option "external display only")... maybe is that ?

Comment: okay, i've learned that the problem isnt the HDMI output, exactly. The problem is the screen, that turns off after 10 minutes, even if its set to never do it.

Comment: i could override this problem with the program called "caffeine". Recommended!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(op solved issue)*

okay, i've learned that the problem isnt the HDMI output, exactly. The problem is the screen, that turns off after 10 minutes, even if its set to never do it. – desert_unbound Dec 18 '11 at 12:28

i could override this problem with the program called "caffeine". Recommended!! – desert_unbound Dec 18 '11 at 16:01